# Не получается вынести поле базы данных из обозревателя серверов на форму visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

сегодня неожиданно возникла такая проблема. Не получается вынести поле базы данных из обозревателя серверов на форму. Во время попытки переноса курсор меняется на перечеркнутый круг давая понять что это сделать нельзя(на скрине к сожалению не отображается курсор). Хотя раньше я спокойно осуществлял данную процедуру и на форму переносился текстбокс с уже установленными связями и лейбл соответствующий названию поля.

[image]

Comment: даже не указали какой язык, я в шоке.

Comment: Все правильно. Такое действие возможно из окна `Data Source`. Вам нужно сначала создать источник данных, а затем в этом окне будет возможна данная функциональность.

Comment: При чем тут язык? Да и я его указал в тегах вроде.